# InvalidQueryException in cassandra when creating cluster

Tags: servlets, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

When I was trying [Playlist tutorial](https://docs.datastax.com/en/playlist/doc/java/playlistConnectToCassandra.html) of Cassandra at the first step, I encountered an Exception.
I create a VM on Google Compute Engine and install cassandra 3.0.10([this link](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/install/installRHEL.html)). Then I did what the tutorial said.

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table schema_keyspaces))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:240)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:86)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1455)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:158)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:329)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:279)
    at playlist.model.CassandraData.createSession(CassandraData.java:66)
    at playlist.model.CassandraData.getSession(CassandraData.java:50)
    at playlist.model.CassandraInfo.<init>(CassandraInfo.java:25)
    at playlist.controller.HomeServlet.doGet(HomeServlet.java:23)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:72)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:742)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:712)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:123)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    ... 38 more
```

Someone said that the version of com.datastax.cassandra doesn't match Cassandra.
In the pom.xml, the version of com.datastax.cassandra is 2.1.10.
Though I changed it to 3.1.0, the exception still appeared.
Which version of com.datastax.cassandra should I adopt?

By the way, I could use com.datastax.cassandra3.1.0 to access Cassandra3.7.
But Using com.datastax.cassandra2.1.10 to access Cassandra3.7 got the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

The problem indeed is the inconsistency of the versions.
When I use `Tomcat` to deploy this application, I could access it from the web browser successfully. However, using `cargo` the tutorial adopted didn't work for me. I'm not familiar with it. Maybe I did something wrong.